# Include Function Result in json Response

Tags: php, json

I am not PHP Developer. I have one Android Application in which I am displaying share and like counts with below API

```
mysqli_query($conn,"SET NAMES utf8");
$sql = "SELECT tbl_quotes.*,au_picture as picture FROM tbl_fav INNER JOIN tbl_quotes INNER JOIN tbl_category  ON user_id='".$userId."' AND qu_author=_auid  AND fav_qu_id=_quid Order By '".$order."' DESC LIMIT ".$limit." OFFSET ".$offset;


$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$arr = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $arr[] = $r;
}

echo json_encode($arr, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Now I want convert that number in K style like below code

```
if ($value > 999 && $value <= 999999) {
    $result = floor($value / 1000) . ' K';
} elseif ($value > 999999) {
    $result = floor($value / 1000000) . ' M';
} else {
    $result = $value;
}
```

like field is qu_like and share field is qu_share. Anyone can please help me how can I use this function for convert numbers and include it in my json ?

Thanks

Comment: which number? Presumably you need to change its value in the array before you convert it to JSON? In that case you should call it inside your while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done with below code....

```
function Get_convert_to($value){


    if ($value > 999 && $value <= 999999) {
    $result = floor($value / 1000) . ' K';
} elseif ($value > 999999) {
    $result = floor($value / 1000000) . ' M';
} else {
    $result = $value;
}


    return $result;
    }
```

its working fine....

Answer (score 0):

To modify the returned array from the DB before JSON encoding you can do as below.

```
<?php
//1. create the formatting function
function formatValue($value) {
    if ($value > 999 && $value <= 999999) {
        return $result = floor($value / 1000) . ' K';
    } elseif ($value > 999999) {
        return $result = floor($value / 1000000) . ' M';
    } else {
        return $result = $value;
    }
}

mysqli_query($conn,"SET NAMES utf8");
$sql = "SELECT tbl_quotes.*,au_picture as picture FROM tbl_fav INNER JOIN tbl_quotes INNER JOIN tbl_category  ON user_id='".$userId."' AND qu_author=_auid  AND fav_qu_id=_quid Order By '".$order."' DESC LIMIT ".$limit." OFFSET ".$offset;


$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
//2. check if there's a result
if($result){
    $arr = array();
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        $arr[] = $r;
    }
    //3. free result set
    mysqli_free_result($result);

    //4. update qu_like and qu_share keys in the $arr array before creating the json
    foreach ($arr as &$value) {
        $value['qu_like'] = formatValue($value['qu_like']);
        $value['qu_share'] = formatValue($value['qu_share']);
    }

    echo json_encode($arr, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Also I think you should bind parameters in your SQL statement. Check if sql below will work. For more details check http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

```
$sql = "SELECT tbl_quotes.*,au_picture as picture FROM tbl_fav INNER JOIN tbl_quotes INNER JOIN tbl_category  ON user_id=? AND qu_author=?  AND fav_qu_id=? Order By ? DESC LIMIT ? OFFSET ?";
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {
    /*i - integer
      d - double
      s - string
      b - BLOB
      change first argument of bind_params to suit your variables :)
    */
    $stmt->bind_params("siisii",$userId,_auid,_auid,$order,$limit,$offset);
    $stmt->execute();
    /* bind result variables */
     $stmt->bind_result($col1,$col2,$col2);
    //then replace while statement above as below
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
      //... echo $col1 etc
    }
}
```